# Azure PowerShell. Reference Virtual Network From Another Resource Group

Tags: azure-powershell

I have a PowerShell script that restrict access to Web Apps down to a subnet from a Virtual Network:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $ResourceGroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $WebAppName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $VirtualNetworkName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $SubnetName
)

Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WebAppName $WebAppName -Name "VPN" -Priority 500 -Action Allow -VirtualNetworkName "$VirtualNetworkName" -SubnetName "$SubnetName"
```

How can I reference Virtual Network that resides in other Resource Group than my Web Apps? [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/add-azwebappaccessrestrictionrule?view=azps-3.6.1) don't seem to have such example. I'm able to reference Virtual Network in another Resource Group in Portal and via ARM Template, but when I use the PowerShell script mentioned above I get:

```
##[error]The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNet1' under resource group 'Test1-RG' was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-SubnetId` parameter to reference the subnet in another resource group.

The SubnetId is like
`"/subscriptions/<subscriptiondID>/resourceGroups/<rgName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnetName>/subnets/<subnetName>"`

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $ResourceGroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $WebAppName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $SubnetId
)

Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WebAppName $WebAppName -Name "VPN" -Priority 500 -Action Allow -SubnetId $SubnetId
```

Comment: `Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WebAppName $WebAppName -Name "VPN" -Priority 500 -Action Allow -SubnetId "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$VirtualNetworkName/subnets/$SubnetName"`
Still getting the same error: `Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule : The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNet1' under resource group 'Test1-RG' was not found.`

Comment: Do you run them in a new PS session? Do you specify the correct resource group name (including your web app)? This works on my side with a subnet in a different rg and vnet than a web app.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't providing correct Resource Group in Virtual Network reference. This works! Thank you!